# QuestDB invalid metadata version

Tags: questdb

When I run QuestDB selects for few tables I started see the error

`Invalid metadata version at fd=34. Metadata version does not match runtime version`

I am running QuestDB docker image `questdb/questdb:6.0.4` and I believe I created the table when I used `questdb/questdb:6.0.5`. Is it possible to downgrade tables in QuestDB or any other way to fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to downgrade from some version to others, but not always.

In particular 6.0.5 can be downgraded to 6.0.4. To do it, in every table directory upgrade process leaves file `_meta.v419`. You need to stop questdb, delete `_meta` and rename `_meta.v419` into `_meta`. Then you delete `dbroot/upgrade.d` and start QuestDB.